# Does changing the playback rate of a source node alter the pitch?

Tags: web-audio-api

According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/playbackRate), the browser applies pitch correction to audio after the `playbackRate` property of a source node is changed.

However, according to [Chrome Developer docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/01/Web-Audio-FAQ?hl=en), changing the `playbackRate` of a source node is a means of varying pitch.

Do the docs contradict? A quick experiment shows that neither Chrome nor Firefox seem to preserve pitch when the playback rate is changed. A higher playback rate yields higher pitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the docs do contradict. As the Chrome FAQ states, there's currently no native pitch correction in the Web Audio API.

Answer (score 2):

The docs in MDN are wrong, I just fixed them. Thanks for telling us !